# Passing a value via Button ( maybe hidden)

Tags: android, button

This code was working until last night, but now now. I'm wanting a value to be record that is linked to the buttons, I have used **set and get tag** but is only returning last value.

```
//create a layout
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);

        // create a list of buttons
        for(x=0; x<3; x++)
        {   

            newBut = new Button(this);  

            newBut.setText("("TEXT");
            newBut.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            newBut.setTag(x); //hide job id within the button.


            newBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    int newValue = Integer.parseInt(newBut.getTag().toString());




              System.out.println(newValue); //this just a test to display the value


               }
            });
            layout.addView(newBut);    
        }
```

Is the error obvious - not to me.

Comment: You want to get the tag from `v`, not `newBut`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is returning the last value, because in all the created listeners you always reference the same button (last value of `newBut` variable), ignoring the actual click source view you have as the argument. Is should be:

```
newBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                int newValue = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                System.out.println(newValue);
           }
        });
```